# Query String in form does not work

Tags: php, forms, query-string

I have the following form in my form.php file:

```
<form action="operation.php?part=dictionary&operation=<?php echo (($_GET['action']=='addword')?'save':'edit&id='.$_GET['id'])?>" method="get">
.....
....
</form>
```

And in my operation.php file:

```
if($_GET['operation']=='save'){
        echo "This is true";
    }else{
        die(mysql_error());
    }
```

And it shows the message that it does not recognize the operation parameter.
So if anyone have any idea of how to distinguish the operation between save and edit would be really appreciated. Thanks you

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing GET vs POST?

Comment: XSS alarm. `$_GET['id']` should be `htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'])`. EDIT: if not cast to int and urlencoded.

Comment: What's the `mysql_error()` there for??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using:

```
<form action="operation.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="part" value="dictionary">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="<?php echo (($_GET['action']=='addword')?'save':'edit&id='.$_GET['id'])?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting a form's method to "GET" results in ignoring all GET-parameter added to the action of the form. In order to get those parameter to work you will have to add them as hidden input fields otherwise you switch your form's method to "POST". This results in setting POST-parameter according to form fields and setting GET-parameter according to the link additions made at form's action.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use hidden parameters to submit values to your form, like so:

```
<form action="operation.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="part" value="dictionary" />
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="<?php echo (($_GET['action']=='addword')?'save':'edit&id='.$_GET['id'])?>" />
</form>
```